# JSON POST using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, post

AngularJS is not creating JSON as desired. With code (below) , it generates array (serialized steam ) but not form . ie
I am getting

```
 {
data : 'value',
date : 'value'
}
```

But wanted - JSON ie

```
{
"data" : "value",
"date" : "value"
}
```

The code for Angular to POST json is ( snippet )

```
<script>
    // Defining angularjs application.
    var postApp = angular.module('postApp', []);
    // Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
    postApp.controller('postController', function($scope, $http) {
      // create a blank object to handle form data.
        $scope.user = {};
      // calling our submit function.
        $scope.submitForm = function() {
        // Posting data to php file
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'user.php',
          data    :JSON.stringify($scope.user),
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
         })
          .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
              // Showing some error which has to come from server
            } else {
                $scope.message = data.message; //make the json
            }
          });
        };
    });
</script>
```

What should i do to get JSON and not Array ?

Comment: could u please tell us what is $scope.user

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data in JSON format you should use JSON.parse();

```
$http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'user.php',
      data    :JSON.parse($scope.user),
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) method?

Answer (score 0):

Solved . 
by using nothing ie.

json: $scope.user it works ...